# How to insert values into two tables with a foreign key relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I created two tables:

- Table `tblStaff` with columns `id` (primary key, auto increment), `name`, `age`, `address`
- Table `tblRoleOfStaff` with columns `id` (primary key, auto increment), `StaffId` (foreign key to `tblStaff`), `RoleId`

I have form to create new staff with existing role. Data sample to insert:

```
(name, age, address, roleId) = ('my name',20,'San Jose', 1)
```

I want to write a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 to insert new staff to `tblStaff` and insert new record into `tbleRoleOfStaff` with `staffId` I just inserted.

What should I do?

I am so sorry if my question is duplicate with other. I am fresher in SQL.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "auto increment".  Are you sure you know what database you are using?

Comment: Thank Gordon Linoff, I am using SQL Server Management Studio and I set Id column with type is int and then setting identity manually with identity increment with value is 1.

Comment: This is typically referred to as an "identity" column in SQL Server; an "auto increment" column in MySQL; a "serial" column in Postgres.  They are all the same thing, but each database has a different syntax.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) second insert into `tblRoleOfStuff` on a place of `StaffId`. Like:

```
insert into tblStaff values
(@name, @age, @address)

insert into tblRoleOfStuff values
(scope_identity(), @roleid)
```

**EDIT**

There too much comments on this answer, so I want to give an explanation.

If OP guarantee that he will not use any triggers he may use `@@IDENTITY` (bad practice), it is sufficient enough to his needs, but best practice to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

> SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like @@IDENTITY, will return the last identity value created in the current session, but it will also limit it to your current scope as well. In other words, it will return the last identity value that you explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user defined function.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will guarantee that you get identity from current operation, not from another connection or last one processed.

Why not `IDENT_CURRENT`? Because

> IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

So you make take last scoped but not current one. Yes, OP can use it too, but it is a bad practice in that situation (like using only `@@IDENTITY`)

Using `OUTPUT` is indeed good practice, but over complicated for only one identity. If OP need to process more then one row in a time - yes, he need  `OUTPUT`.

Comment: most of the time @@identity will probably get what you want but do a search for @@Identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY etc. it is very easy to write a trigger or a multi statement stored procedure that will mess up which identity you are really trying to get.

Comment: OP question is about simple form with 4 fields. @@IDENTITY is all he need in that case. If he has something with insert of big amount of data - yes, @@IDENTITY will not be enough.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_S thanks for explanation, I changed my answer to SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: @gofr1 Scope_Identity() is not a good solution for a big and busy system. using IDENT_CURRENT is better that using Scope_Identity().

Comment: @marc_s I am sticking with OUTPUT clause even Microsoft says potential of incorrect values with SCOPE_IDENTITY() plus note this answer originally said @@IDENTITY.  This question is definitely a duplicate! https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019779 I understand in OPs particular example either SCOPE_IDENTITY() or @@IDENTITY should be sufficient but things change someone else writes a trigger he isn't aware of etc.  I have literally never seen someone write a trigger that will alter the IDENTITY column and change the output inserted.id value though I suppose even that is possible

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian yes, it is not good for a busy system (I already wrote that in a comment above), but here is a simple form with 4 fields and SCOPE_IDENTITY is sufficient enough for this purpose.

Comment: @Matt this problem was fixed in 2008 R2, and OP use SQL Server 2014, so he can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`/`@@IDENTITY` without any problems. I add information about triggers in my answer as well. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 7):

Because it seems like you are discussing 1 row at a time some people may tell you to use a system vairable like `@@IDENTITY` or some of the others but to ensure with more certainty I recommend the `OUTPUT` clause of the insert statement.  The good thing about this method is it can easily be adapted to handle more than 1 row at a time.

```
DECLARE @Output AS TABLE (StaffId INT)

INSERT INTO tblStaff (name, age, address)
OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @Output (StaffId)
VALUES (@name, @age, @address)

DECLARE @StaffId INT
SELECT @StaffId = StaffId FROM @Output

INSERT INTO tblRoleOfStaff (StaffId, RoleId)
VALUES (@StaffId,@RoleId)
```

Reasons not to use `@@IDENTITY` in case another operation linked to yours is performed.  E.g. a trigger inserts another row into another table, or updates another record in your database., `SCOPE_IDENTITY` has a similar shortfall when a trigger modifies the same table.  `IDENT_CURRENT` has a short coming too.  Do an internet search to learn more there are tons of great resources on these.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `output` from your first insert statement.

```
declare @tmp table(id int)
insert tblStaff (name, age, address)
OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @tmp (id)
values (@name, @age, @address)

declare @roleId int = 1 --or whatever
insert tblRoleOfStaff (staffId,roleId)
select id, @roleId
from @tmp
```

You can insert several roles at once as well.

```
create table Roles (roleId int identity(1,1) primary key, 
RoleName varchar(50),
isDefaultRole bit default 0
)
--mark some roles as default (`isDefaultRole = 1`)
--the 2nd insert will be
insert tblRoleOfStaff (staffId,roleId)
select id, roleId
from @tmp
cross join Roles
where isDefaultRole = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one staff row that you would insert at a time, you could do the following:

```
begin try
 begin tran
  insert into tblStaff (name, age, address) values('my name',20,'San Jose');
  insert into tbleRoleOfStaff (StaffId, RoleId) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 1); 
 commit
end try
begin catch
  IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK;
end catch
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Create Procedure Pro_XXX()
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblStaff (name, age, address, roleId) VALUES ('my name',20,'San Jose', 1);

INSERT INTO tbleRoleOfStaff VALUES (staffId, roleId) VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('tblStaff'),0)

END
```

Please note to the differences between `IDENT_CURRENT`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `@@IDENTITY`. Read about it [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Pinal Dave actually recommends to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in that article you linked to: _To avoid the potential problems associated with adding a trigger later on, always use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the identity of the recently added row in your T SQL Statement or stored procedure._

Answer (score -2):

After the insert into the first table use something like

```sql
DECLARE @staffId INT
SET @staffId = (SELECT TOP 1 id from tblStaff order by id desc)

INSERT INTO tblRoleOfStaff (staffId,roleId) VALUES (@staffId, 2)
```

Comment: This will ***NOT*** work in a busy system! You ***CANNOT*** rely on the "fact" that the last inserted row has the highest `Id` - other inserts may have happened *before* you get a chance to read that value!

Comment: Agreed. But given the table structure and the fact that this a fresher trying out SQL I wasn't worrying about a busy system. My bad.

Comment: @Sam, although it's quite obvious that this will not work on a busy system, also coincidence might also appear, making the system "break" for the user. Might aswell explain it the right way, right?